# Prevent submit on a jQuery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, preventdefault

I'm setting up a password control on a login form with jQuery and ajax.
So far, this is the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var password = $('#login-password').val();
        var email = $('#login-email').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/password_check/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                password: password,
                email: email
            },
            success: function(result) {
                document.getElementById("login-error").innerHTML = result.response;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

With this, the error gets caught when firing the submit button, but if the password is correct the submit doesn't work (even though the error doesn't show up anymore).
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an asynchronous ajax call, so by the time your `success` function fires, the form submit event has passed so you need to submit the form again but use the DOM method, which will bypass the jQuery event handler and allow the form to submit.

```
success: function(result) {
    if(result == "correct"){
        document.getElementById("login-form").submit();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("login-error").innerHTML = result.response;
    }
}
```

As you didnt say what response indicates a correct password, I have used `result == "correct"`, so change that accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return false only if u dont want to submit the form.
If password is correct you need to return true in your case.

Comment: A correct password is determined by an async ajax call, therefore any `return true` would occur before the ajax completes.

Comment: In that case, the ajax call determine if password is correct, and if it's correct he want to submit the form, so he have to return true in the success method. Read the question ...

Comment: The ajax call is asynchronous. The submit event doesn't wait on that call, it completes long before the ajax gets a response. Your answer is basically the same as the other, which was deleted after the user realised it is incorrect.

Comment: Return true in the submit method on the form will submit the form, return false will not. If password is ok, return true, else return false and print the error. This is a good way to do it, and it permit to not reload the form in an javascript variable as you do.

Comment: With an asynchronous ajax call, what you describe is a broken concept. I invite you to make a test example and try it. I guarantee it will not work.